# How to take action on a test failure with pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm using pytest.

I would like to gather/save some data for postmortem analysis on a test failure. I can write a `teardown_method`, but I don't see a way to obtain test status in that context.

Is it possible to take an action on any test (or `assertion`) failure?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Implement a `pytest_exception_interact` in a `conftest.py` file, which according to the [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=pytest_exception_interact#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_exception_interact):

> called when an exception was raised which can potentially be interactively handled.

```
def pytest_exception_interact(node, call, report):
    if report.failed:
        # call.excinfo contains an ExceptionInfo instance
```

It's not clear from your question exactly what you want to gather from the error, but probably having access to an `ExceptionInfo` instance should be enough for your case.

Comment: Interesting! Do you know how I can get a reference to my test object from inside of pytest_exception_interact?

Comment: Explore `node` on a debugger... if your test functions are defined in a class, I believe `node.parent.obj` will give you access to the test class instance.

Comment: Actually, that's node.parent._obj but yes that works great, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it in the second half of a yield fixture:

https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#making-test-result-information-available-in-fixtures

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)