# How do I run a fixture only when the test fails?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I have the following example:

**conftest.py:**

```
@pytest.fixture:
def my_fixture_1(main_device)
  yield
  if FAILED:
    -- code lines --
  else:
    pass
```

**main.py:**

```
def my_test(my_fixture_1):
  main_device = ...
  -- code lines --
  assert 0

  -- code lines --
  assert 1
```

When assert 0, for example, the test should fail and execute *my_fixture_1*. If the test pass, the fixture must not execute. I tried using *hookimpl* but didn't found a solution, the fixture is always executing even if the test pass.

Note that *main_device* is the device connected where my test is running.

Comment: I think... a fixture is not exactly what you need, or at least it doesn't match the flow you want. I fixture is meant to provide some data/object to be used _as part of a test_. Since you put `my_fixture_1` as a parameter to your test, pytest runs your fixture code, up to `yield` to yield control to your test. Even before your `assert 0`, the fixture already partially ran.

Comment: Maybe this? [How to take action on a test failure with pytest?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28201810/2745495)

Answer (score 2):

In [Simon Hawe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71275959/2745495), `request.session.testsfailed` denotes the number of test failures in that particular test run.

Here is an alternative solution that I can think of.

```
import os


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def main_device():
    return None


@pytest.fixture(scope='function', autouse=True)
def my_fixture_1(main_device):
    yield
    if os.environ["test_result"] == "failed":
        print("+++++++++ Test Failed ++++++++")
    elif os.environ["test_result"] == "passed":
        print("+++++++++ Test Passed ++++++++")
    elif os.environ["test_result"] == "skipped":
        print("+++++++++ Test Skipped ++++++++")


def pytest_runtest_logreport(report):
    if report.when == 'call':
        os.environ["test_result"] = report.outcome
```

You can do your implementations directly in the `pytest_runtest_logreport` hook itself. But the drawback is that you won't get access to the fixtures other than the report.

So, if you need `main_device`, you have to go with a custom fixture like as shown above.

Use `@pytest.fixture(scope='function', autouse=True)` which will automatically run it for every test case. you don't have to give `main_device` in all test functions as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `request` as an argument to your fixture. From that, you can check the status of the corresponding tests, i.e. if it has failed or not. In case it failed, you can execute the code you want to get executed on failure. In code that reads as

```py
@pytest.fixture
def my_fixture_1(request):
  yield
  if request.session.testsfailed:
    print("Only print if failed")
```

Of course, the fixture will always run but the branch will only be executed if the corresponding test failed.

Comment: you might also want to store the `request.session.testfailed` value before the `yield` and compare it to the value after the `yield`, in case you are running multiple tests with each getting its own instance of this fixture; otherwise your code will run for all tests after the first failed one and not just the failed ones